# CoinMarketCap API latest global metrics inconsistent

Tags: coinmarketcap

I've integrated the CoinMarketCap API to fetch the current total market cap through: https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global-metrics/quotes/latest

This market-cap data updates every 5 minutes, XX:X4:10 and XX:X9:10. Im unable to fetch the latter through API, as the timing seem off.

For example, when I fetch the total market cap at XX:55:XX, it returns an updated date of XX:54:XX. Fine so far. However, at XX:59:XX it still returns XX:54:XX, which could still be fine. Though, at XX:01:XX it already returns (a future) time of XX:04:XX.

Therefore, it's impossible to fetch the XX:X9:10 total market cap entry from the latest global metrics endpoint, which equals to 50% of the total entries missed over any time interval...

Is there anybody with the same issue?

***I've already checked, the server time is in sync with the API returned time***

***Yes, I could use the 'Quotes historical' global metrics endpoint, but this requires a paid subscription***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted CoinMarketCap support and they indeed agreed this was an API issue. They deployed a fix for this last week so it's no longer an issue